# Postman authorization without username (just password)

Tags: curl, postman, mixpanel

I am trying to explore the mixpanel API with Postman.

This is the url I am supposed to call:

```
curl https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/segmentation/ \
    -u YOUR_API_SECRET: \
    -d from_date="2016-02-11" -d to_date="2016-02-11" -d event="Viewed Page"
```

I am able to get this to work on curl, but not on Postman.

I can't find an authorization that allows me to just use the password without the login.

Any help here?

Comment: in your curl example, YOUR_API_SECRET is the username, not the password.

Answer (score 1):

From curl's man page:

```
-u, --user <user:password>
```

Perhaps the user is set up as `YOUR_API_SECRET`
Have you tried using that as the username in Postman?

Just having a password on an API would be rather insecure